# Update field with Hardcore and computed field in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a program where after X happen, I set the date to the first of July of the following year.

```
UPDATE dbo.PAY_paymentDetails 
SET nextPayment = CASE 
                     WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, dateMade) < 7 
                          AND DATEPART(YEAR, dateMade) = DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()) 
                        THEN DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE())) 
                     ELSE DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE() + 1) 
                  END
```

So I add a year to the current year using

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(YEAR,1,GETDATE())
```

and this results in 2017, But I can't figure out how to manipulate my tsql so give me 2017-07-01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you are only selecting the Year from the datepart function. If you do something like

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(DATEPART(DAY, DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR) AS DATE)
```

then you'd get what you are looking for. Not the prettiest hack but it works. Hope it helps..